# How to implement Spring Method level security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-aop

I want to implement Spring Method level security. For that what I have done  is

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity 
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig  extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
@Autowired
private AccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler;

@Autowired
private AdminPortalAuthProvider authProvider;

@Autowired
private AdminWebAuthDetailsSource authenticationDetailsSource;

@Autowired
AdminAuthSuccessHandler successHandler;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
    .csrf().csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository()).and()
        .antMatcher("/admin/**")
        .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/admin/registration","/admin/setPassword").anonymous()
        .antMatchers("/admin/setPass").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .formLogin()
            .authenticationDetailsSource(authenticationDetailsSource)
            .usernameParameter("username")
            .passwordParameter("password")
            .loginPage("/admin/login")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/admin/home")
            .successHandler(successHandler)
            .permitAll()
         .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/admin/logout")
            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .permitAll()

         .and()
            .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler)
        .and()
            .authenticationProvider(authProvider)
         .addFilterAfter(new CsrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class)
         .addFilterAfter(new CustomSecurityFilter(),BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
         .headers().xssProtection().and().frameOptions().sameOrigin()
        .cacheControl().and().contentTypeOptions();   

}


private CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {
    HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository repository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
    repository.setHeaderName("X-XSRF-TOKEN");
    return repository;
}

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
  web.ignoring().antMatchers("/js/**","/css/**","/img/**","/customjs/**","/fonts/**","/lib/**","/icons-reference/**","/admin/registration/**","/admin/customer/payment-invoice-pg-post");
}
```

}

and I am using `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"))`

on method but still it is not working...
 can any one help me please.....

> as I have been asked to put my securityConfig code where all about the url security , here I have edited my question...

Comment: *it is not working* - this is not a valid description of your error.

Comment: thanks for your comment but there is no error statement, there is no effect of using @PreAuthorize in code.

Comment: Show your full `SecurityConfig` class and the class with `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"))`.

Comment: In which file you have define which user has admin role ?

Comment: Actually in my project, 1 user can have multiple role, and role list of a user is coming for Database and then I am appending it in authorities as List<GrantedAuthority>.

Comment: Can you show the code where you defines your roles ?

Comment: @OresteViron as  I mentioned in previous comment its coming from DB.

Comment: Is the class that you're adding `@PreAuthorize` to one that gets introspected by spring-security? You can't just add it to any old POJO method. Please update your question with that part of the code.

Comment: @Andy Brown I have tried to use **PreAuthorize** on methods of  **Service, Controller** and **interface** of service class but there is no effect of PreAuthorize on methods.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to try once using **GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration** class.

```
 @Configuration
 @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
  prePostEnabled = true)
 public class MethodSecurityConfig 
  extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {
 }
```

Comment: That is not neccessary, it should work with annotation only.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have tried according to you but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

After the deep study of code and concepts and with help of my seniors, I got the solution of my Question...

Along with the spring **method level security**...

At ***first*** I found that I need to use concept of **AOP** 
So, I added the required dependency in pom.xml

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-aop -->
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
       <version>5.0.1.RELEASE</version>
   </dependency>
```

and place the annotation **@EnableAspectJAutoProxy** in the same file where **@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)** is defined.

Still I found that **@PreAuthorize** has no effect on code.

Then ***Second*** I got another root cause that was...

In my project some dependencies are provided in tomcat's lib folder also due to which project got two instances of few dependencies at run time so conflicts were there(*but these conflicts are not reflected in eclipse*).

So I exclude those dependencies in pom.xml

and the result was..... @PreAuthorize is working correctly.